# What is the meaning of "ので" and "会う" here?

Tags: meaning

> 正月に大ぜいの客が来るので, 会うのが面倒だと思う人もある
> Some people do not want to have to take care of the large number of visitors who shows up during the New Year

Why is "ので" used here? I would translate it like "because of people who shows up during the New Year", but my translation doesn't connect with "会う" and with the second part of the sentence

Answer (score 1):

`面倒` means also "trouble, bother", so I think a more literal translation would be "Since [ので] a lot of people come during New Year, there are people who think it's a bother [面倒] to meet [会う]"; maybe the translator used "Do no want to take care" for `会うのが面倒` (which I think means, literally, "It's a bother to meet [them]") and rephrased it to remove "Since/ので".